# Dividing the screen into three columns Angular Material Design

Tags: angularjs, angularjs-material

I am new to Angular Material Design.   I want to design a form which divides the date into three columns. I created two forms .  The first form contains two div's and second form contain one div.  I want each div in separate columns of the screen and Three div's should divide the screen width equally let's say 33.33% of 100% width but I am getting all the div's in only one column.  Given below is the code I wrote:

```
<body ng-app="inputErrorsAdvancedApp"> 
   <div ng-controller="AppCtrl" layout="column" ng-cloak>
     <div md-content layout-padding>
       <form name="userForm">
        <div layout-xs="column">  
          <md-input-container class="md-block" flex="30">
            <label>First Name</label>
            <input>
          </md-input-container> 
          <md-input-container class="md-block" flex="30">
           <label>Last Name</label>
           <input>
          </md-input-container> 
          <md-input-container class="md-block" flex="30">
            <label>Date Of Birth</label>
            <input>
            </md-input-container>
          <md-input-container class="md-block" flex="30">
            <label>Gender</label>
            <input>
            </md-input-container>
          <md-input-container class="md-block" flex="30">
            <label>Email</label>
            <input>
          </md-input-container>
         <md-input-container class="md-block" flex="30">
           <label>Mobile</label>
           <input>
         </md-input-container>
         <md-input-container class="md-block" flex="30">
           <label>Address</label>
           <input>
         </md-input-container>
         <md-input-container class="md-block" flex="30">
           <label>City</label>
           <input>
        </md-input-container>     
  </div>
  <div layout-xs="column">
    <md-input-container class="md-block" flex="30">
      <label>Country</label>
      <input>
    </md-input-container>
    <md-input-container class="md-block" flex="30">
      <label>State</label>
      <input>
    </md-input-container>
    <md-input-container class="md-block" flex="30">
     <label>Phone</label>
     <input>
    </md-input-container>
    <md-input-container class="md-block" flex="30">
      <label>Alternate Email</label>
      <input>
    </md-input-container>
    <md-input-container class="md-block" flex="30">
      <label>Alternate Mobile</label>
      <input>
    </md-input-container>
  </div>
</form>
<form name="security">
   <div layout-xs="column">
   <md-input-container class="md-block" flex="30">
     <label>old password</label>
    <input>
   </md-input-container>
   <md-input-container class="md-block" flex="30">
    <label>New Password</label>
    <input>
   </md-input-container>
   <md-input-container class="md-block" flex="30">
    <label>Re-Enter Password</label>
    <input>
   </md-input-container>    
  </div>
 </form>
 </div>
```

Here is the plunker for the page I created

https://plnkr.co/edit/nj5o59A3NmqZtCv7HOfy?p=preview

Please help me as how to resolve this issue.

Comment: Please post your edit to my answer as a comment or new question. I'm glad to be helpful!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use `layout="row"` on the parent element. For example

`<div layout="row" md-content layout-padding>
    ...forms...
</div>`

Link to the docs: https://material.angularjs.org/latest/layout/container

Comment: Thank You so much for the answer.I did as per your instructions the data is divided into three columns but the three columns are not fitted to the entire screen of  desktop.  Here is the plunker is I updated  https://plnkr.co/edit/nj5o59A3NmqZtCv7HOfy?p=preview

Comment: You can set flex="50" on the forms to make them fill the page.

Comment: I tried by applying the flex attribute, but still it is not fitted to the entire screen of desktop.   Thank you for the guidance.

Answer (score 0):

You flex is like the dividing the screen. You can use like this. The screen must be divide to 100%. If you use 3 div or md-input-container flex should be 33. i.e 100/3. If you have 4 divs you should divide the screen 100% to 4 equal parts.

```
    <div layout-xs="column">  
              <md-input-container class="md-block" flex="33">
                <label>First Name</label>
                <input>
              </md-input-container> 
              <md-input-container class="md-block" flex="33">
               <label>Last Name</label>
               <input>
              </md-input-container> 
              <md-input-container class="md-block" flex="33">
                <label>Date Of Birth</label>
                <input>
              </md-input-container>
</div>
```

For more information visit the angular material official website.